# Magento - BtB and BtC different amounts

Tags: magento

I am going to make a new webshop in Magento, and I have a problem that I can find a solution on.

When a BtB customer is buy a product, the there have to be some minimum amounts pr. product. So lets say a BtB customer will buy a chair, then they need to buy 5 chairs, then cannot only buy 1.

But the BtC customers can choose as many the wants. So if the BtC customers only wants to buy 1 then is okay.

I have search after a module or solution on this problem, but I cant find any?

Regards,

Kristoffer

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System >> Configuration >> Inventory Tab` and find the `Product Stock Options` to limit the product restriction based on user groups

[image]

Comment: But what if I need minimum amounts pr. product, and if it is different from product to product?

Comment: go for a module , I mean make your observer than , that will detect user group and restrict

Comment: But I have searched for a module, and I'cant find anything with that function.

Comment: Create your own my friend :)